# Design automation, workitem output changed after processing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

On some occasion, it seems that my workitems output arguments are modified after processing.

This is my workitem when i post it :

```
{
  "ActivityId": "CleanActivity",
  "Arguments": {
    "InputArguments": [
      {
        "Headers": [],
        "Name": "HostDwg",
        "Resource": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Originals/EDL%20150%20lgts%20REHA%20CREIL%202018-07-20%2016-43-30/Test/plans%20pro%20etat%20existant%20st%C3%A9arinerie%20r%2B1-test.dwg?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI5VTPS3Y53Z4U5JQ/20180723/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180723T090448Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f94b5152fd47744bb75ee96fe4449cdbe8953a5a286699d3bb2f2d7c4aff3e85",
        "StorageProvider": "Generic"
      }
    ],
    "OutputArguments": [
      {
        "Headers": [],
        "HttpVerb": "PUT",
        "Name": "Result",
        "Resource": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ToDo/EDL%20150%20lgts%20REHA%20CREIL%202018-07-20%2016-43-30/Test/plans%20pro%20etat%20existant%20st%C3%A9arinerie%20r%2B1-test.dwg?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI5VTPS3Y53Z4U5JQ/20180723/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180723T090448Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=8770617a49e37e5aaa44f06dc16682740663021219f64a031a772289d05fcb6d",
        "StorageProvider": "Generic"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is what I get, once the workitem status is succeeded :

```
{
  "ActivityId": "CleanActivity",
  "Arguments": {
    "InputArguments": [
      {
        "Headers": [],
        "Name": "HostDwg",
        "Resource": "https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Originals/EDL%20150%20lgts%20REHA%20CREIL%202018-07-20%2016-43-30/Test/plans%20pro%20etat%20existant%20st%C3%A9arinerie%20r%2B1-test.dwg?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI5VTPS3Y53Z4U5JQ/20180723/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180723T090448Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f94b5152fd47744bb75ee96fe4449cdbe8953a5a286699d3bb2f2d7c4aff3e85",
        "StorageProvider": "Generic"
      }
    ],
    "OutputArguments": [
      {
        "Headers": [],
        "HttpVerb": "PUT",
        "Name": "Result",
        "Resource": "https://acadio.s3.amazonaws.com/aces-workitem-outputs/b867ae2d096c496aa20ca5ce421610d4/result.dwg?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIL577XFNNPATMNLA&Expires=1532343691&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzEFoaDPkC0MweiQFC8T%2BQZyK3AzuHIkNxqMhuk2JvGaWLY6gNF%2FxoABlzczm83tmwR95naatHDxb4kvGvGuGrSUmsiFN4Zm3YUpozTA6f05VKQSveiXI6F6Fgvc29v4BJHYVB9y8gf6FDqHkFv7NeJPybT1Ie8T7EAdEWnTB%2Fnxj9Uw59CgviXTLxbnimyFYVaQIzNOgUfGnMczG9aq6RMLVplm7ZpXFJGy%2BV8zEewTRv%2BIAqEu8VfQXi2pIpn06LIH8BcLuSAgpNzEiyLcadeMIHEwCdqsNeAjMLqOCvYNN2gtMfOXXLm6%2FO60tFQfvfOmyhzasLABDsjFl9Mt3QiuU7OIpJ32qmhRv6eiNqPh1ROHJRJ6%2BV0MgDBDzr6QHXBJc5gKBXOFAhH94K1KgTo%2B6SvaXNCwdOfnO58YRoTI6g8%2B5K5GOAu%2BJ3JLOINTGeVz0yRQDYb63O%2BF%2Fj0N72i%2BbNYy5rBR3GjsJa296KDXcL68v9cH5YYAyrfGKlYUii73lPLxA8RiG%2BCLsypDnRPFelyak5BnLa5iubXkObpsqCKTnRQ3A%2BrWiZUhg55euNDMa9We2hGI%2FzRyVO%2Bdz%2FgofCQ%2FrOm9eb2%2FMolbPW2gU%3D&Signature=BZgfra8Zlw4X9yBA3K0%2BXb3p7Sw%3D",
        "StorageProvider": "Generic"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the report.log I get in the StatusDetails field :

```
[07/23/2018 09:11:33] Starting work item 6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1
[07/23/2018 09:11:33] Start download phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:33] Start downloading file https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Originals/EDL%20150%20lgts%20REHA%20CREIL%202018-07-20%2016-43-30/Test/plans%20pro%20etat%20existant%20st%C3%A9arinerie%20r%2B1-test.dwg?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI5VTPS3Y53Z4U5JQ/20180723/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180723T090448Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f94b5152fd47744bb75ee96fe4449cdbe8953a5a286699d3bb2f2d7c4aff3e85.
[07/23/2018 09:11:33] Start preparing AppPackage Fc4aPackage.
[07/23/2018 09:11:33] Reuse previously downloaded app from local cache.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] End downloading file https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Originals/EDL%20150%20lgts%20REHA%20CREIL%202018-07-20%2016-43-30/Test/plans%20pro%20etat%20existant%20st%C3%A9arinerie%20r%2B1-test.dwg?X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAI5VTPS3Y53Z4U5JQ/20180723/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180723T090448Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f94b5152fd47744bb75ee96fe4449cdbe8953a5a286699d3bb2f2d7c4aff3e85. 48436 bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\plans pro etat existant stéarinerie r+1-test.dwg.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] End download phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Start script content.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] _.fclean
_.saveas

result.dwg

[07/23/2018 09:11:34] End script content.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Command line: /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\plans pro etat existant stéarinerie r+1-test.dwg" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\Fc4aPackage[429fb65a-a7a7-49bf-b687-c6c7aae52913].package" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\script.scr"
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Start script phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1 "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\userdata" /exe "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe"  /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\plans pro etat existant stéarinerie r+1-test.dwg" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\Fc4aPackage[429fb65a-a7a7-49bf-b687-c6c7aae52913].package" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\script.scr".
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\tmp\accc16282).
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Isolating to regKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\userdata.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Launching sandbox process: [T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\plans pro etat existant stéarinerie r+1-test.dwg" /al T:\Aces\Applications\Fc4aPackage[429fb65a-a7a7-49bf-b687-c6c7aae52913].package /s T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\script.scr  /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1 T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\userdata]
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Waiting for child process to complete: 352
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\tmp\accc42882).
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2018 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (P.45.Z.20)
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Execution Path:
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\userdata.
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Version Number: P.45.Z.20 (UNICODE)
[07/23/2018 09:11:34] Regenerating model.
[07/23/2018 09:11:35] Command:
[07/23/2018 09:11:35] Command:
[07/23/2018 09:11:35] Command:
[07/23/2018 09:11:35] Command: _.fclean
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] FINALCAD Plotter Ready
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Command: _.saveas
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Current file format: AutoCAD 2018 Drawing
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Enter file format [R14(LT98&LT97)/2000(LT2000)/2004(LT2004)/2007(LT2007)/2010(LT2010)/2013(LT2013)/2018(LT2018)/DXF/Template] <2018>:
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Save drawing as <T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\plans pro etat existant stéarinerie r+1-test.dwg>: result.dwg
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Command: _.quit
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Process exit code: 0
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] End script phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Start upload phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Uploading T:\Aces\Jobs\6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1\result.dwg to https://acadio.s3.amazonaws.com/aces-workitem-outputs/6db95c309a1d4e9397e1bb41d80d60a1/result.dwg?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIBFIHQ7UR5VQQEXQ&Expires=1532340697&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzEFoaDKcXGBN40uwQnMBT%2BiK3A4rnqflHnGMnEZHqy3JnmXTJQogAlYlQW1YXd2u3XePZzgQCGoXjSHDRy6zFe1ljVl2WHlvJq7tBVfXRfpHHnWMmdgiQGkvRMWLfrBoZ5A4PQEDTz4CzU%2FqZtvfeVzqY9wsivnIQPAig%2BGKUDq9pUdpZ9KkqfnC9RgzEhtoyBC4l0M5KzHU%2FG7aKuItLx0h7u714Vr%2BT7TTeK4GE5yXsx5U3pReiFWzh2xhDgm0qIhHmls3SlfReCfgr%2BOKOGDNEFvasMeo0LuiO4ADJwKTiBdR88NCRHaWSFLmixklv5yK6IoCx1XyETlvsJSmoSxM9fAyEo%2Fkm1Mk%2FNj4Z6CqEVZ8GS8kenOoqCoVlNtNpGewLZPpldcUTGZbhtYnj%2BvlWpx8Iv6dvm2yjNkFUIDAfjDVD6hs0SBI7aSE8JLoJGaZyNzWkWKrWXdRNYnzNkXc10U1fTiPbpMt9MY3Oefq%2FIty24BiPKY%2BT%2BB6RxHYczqUCAKzvHYIyvumWJIxOtxg%2Bkc%2BgRTPmsxq9vBuO6zecgFyfeL%2BEjXS2fdRwfZy4oZYqZvwJ5sF3dtIUxVCxZMRdOAMiZBTFWf8or6bW2gU%3D&Signature=zt7984os81KubPzFrym%2FhVDrds8%3D.
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] End upload phase.
[07/23/2018 09:11:36] Job finished with result Succeeded
```

I don't understand why my output url has been changed to an acadio one. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/) `v2` will try to save the output on the `OutputArgument.Result` URL, if not possible, will override this parameter and save to its own S3 bucket (as you noticed).

Comment: But why is it only happenning on dwg containing a "+" in their file name even though the S3 presigned url is valid. For example : Plans PRO Etat existant Stéarinerie R+3.dwg.

Comment: That may be causing a problem on validation, usually the + sign has a special meaning on URLs, does the presigned url works on the browser?

Comment: Since the url is encoded, the "+" became "%2B". And yes, it's working on the browser.

Comment: Could you tell me once it's deployed? Thanks.

Comment: @RomainDAROCHA it should be live now! Thanks!